# Cinnamon Settings appears as Bluetooth in Docky

Tags: icons, cinnamon, docky

Recently, I switched over to Cinnamon and Docky as my main WM and it's so far been great.

However, I've noticed that the Control Panel/Settings app has the Bluetooth icon (and the Bluetooth name) in the dock.

> [image]

Is there any way I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Open `/home/*user*/.cache/docky` or `/app/docky-2/Docky/Interface/DockPreferences/Dock1/Launchers` with `gedit` and replace the line

```
/usr/share/applications/cinnamon-bluetooth-properties.desktop
```

by

```
/usr/share/applications/cinnamon-settings.desktop
```

If anyone need it (I'm french):

```
Icon=preferences-system
Name[fr]=Paramètres systèmes
Comment[fr]=Configurer les paramètres systèmes
```

You have to restart Docky after that ! 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint/+bug/1222225

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
gedit ~/.cache/docky/docky.desktop.en_US.UTF-8.cache
```

locate both `[/usr/share/applications/cinnamon-settings.desktop]` and `[/usr/share/applications/cinnamon-bluetooth-properties.desktop]` portion in the file. Move the total segment of `[/usr/share/applications/cinnamon-settings.desktop]` before `[/usr/share/applications/cinnamon-bluetooth-properties.desktop]`.

This can be like:

```
[/usr/share/applications/cinnamon-settings.desktop]
Exec=cinnamon-settings
Icon=preferences-system
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Settings;
StartupNotify=false
OnlyShowIn=X-Cinnamon;
Keywords=Preferences;Settings;
Name=System Settings
Comment=Control Center

[/usr/share/applications/cinnamon-bluetooth-properties.desktop]
Icon=bluetooth
Exec=cinnamon-settings bluetooth
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=GTK;Settings;X-Cinnamon-NetworkSettings;HardwareSettings;X-Cinnamon-Settings-Panel;
OnlyShowIn=X-Cinnamon;
StartupNotify=true
X-Cinnamon-Settings-Panel=bluetooth
Name=Bluetooth
Comment=Configure Bluetooth settings
```

Then Sign Out & Sign back In .
It worked for me with Linux Mint 17.3 Cinnamon 64-bit
& Cinnamon Version 2.8.6

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in linuxmint 18: about the control-centre icon in docky has the hp_print icon . This is my file "docky.desktop.en_US.UTF-8.cache". 
I try to move the total segment of [/usr/share/applications/cinnamon-control-center.desktop] on top, but nothing has happened. Thanks a lot.

[/usr/share/applications/cinnamon-control-center.desktop]
Name=Cinnamon Control Center
Icon=preferences-system
Exec=cinnamon-control-center --overview
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=GTK;System;
OnlyShowIn=X-Cinnamon;
NoDisplay=true
Keywords=Preferences;Settings;

[/usr/share/applications/cinnamon-color-panel.desktop]
Exec=cinnamon-settings color
Icon=cs-color
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=GTK;Settings;X-Cinnamon-Settings-Panel;HardwareSettings
OnlyShowIn=X-Cinnamon;
X-Cinnamon-Settings-Panel=color
Keywords=Color;ICC;Profile;Calibrate;Printer;Display;
Name=Colore
Comment=Impostazioni di gestione del colore

[/usr/share/applications/cinnamon-datetime-panel.desktop]
Name=Date & Time
Comment=Date and Time preferences panel
Exec=cinnamon-control-center datetime
Icon=cs-date-time
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=GTK;Settings;X-cinnamon-SystemSettings;X-Cinnamon-Settings-Panel;
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;
X-Cinnamon-Settings-Panel=datetime
Keywords=Clock;Timezone;Location;
NoDisplay=true

[/usr/share/applications/cinnamon-display-panel.desktop]
Exec=cinnamon-settings display
Icon=cs-display
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=GTK;Settings;HardwareSettings;X-Cinnamon-Settings-Panel;
OnlyShowIn=X-Cinnamon;
X-Cinnamon-Settings-Panel=display
Keywords=Panel;Projector;xrandr;Screen;Resolution;Refresh;
Name=Monitor
Comment=Cambia la risoluzione e la posizione dei monitor e dei proiettori

[/usr/share/applications/cinnamon-menu-editor.desktop]
Name=Cinnamon Menu Editor
Comment=Edit the entries of the Cinnamon menu applet
Exec=cinnamon-menu-editor
Icon=alacarte
OnlyShowIn=X-Cinnamon;
Terminal=false
Type=Application
NoDisplay=true
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Settings;DesktopSettings;
StartupNotify=false

[/usr/share/applications/cinnamon-network-panel.desktop]
Exec=cinnamon-settings network
Icon=cs-network
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=GTK;Settings;HardwareSettings;X-Cinnamon-Settings-Panel;
OnlyShowIn=X-Cinnamon;
X-Cinnamon-Settings-Panel=network
Keywords=Network;Wireless;IP;LAN;Proxy;
Name=Rete
Comment=Impostazioni di rete

[/usr/share/applications/cinnamon-region-panel.desktop]
Exec=cinnamon-settings region
Icon=cs-language
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=GTK;Settings;DesktopSettings;X-Cinnamon-Settings-Panel;X-Cinnamon-PersonalSettings
OnlyShowIn=X-Cinnamon;
X-Cinnamon-Settings-Panel=region
Keywords=Language;Layout;Keyboard;
NoDisplay=true
Name=Regione e lingua
Comment=Cambia le impostazioni della tua regione e della lingua

[/usr/share/applications/cinnamon-screensaver.desktop]
Type=Application
Name=Screensaver
Comment=Launch screensaver and locker program
Icon=preferences-desktop-screensaver
Exec=cinnamon-screensaver
OnlyShowIn=X-Cinnamon
NoDisplay=true
X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=20
X-GNOME-Autostart-Phase=Application
X-GNOME-Autostart-Notify=true
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=cinnamon-screensaver
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=general
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Version=2.2.4
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=cinnamon-screensaver

[/usr/share/applications/cinnamon-settings-applets.desktop]
Icon=cs-applets
Exec=cinnamon-settings applets
Type=Application
OnlyShowIn=X-Cinnamon;
Categories=Settings;
Name=Applet
Comment=Gestione applet di Cinnamon

[/usr/share/applications/cinnamon-settings-backgrounds.desktop]
Icon=cs-backgrounds
Exec=cinnamon-settings backgrounds
Type=Application
OnlyShowIn=X-Cinnamon;
Categories=Settings;
Name=Sfondi
Comment=Cambia sfondo scrivania

[/usr/share/applications/cinnamon-settings-calendar.desktop]
Icon=cs-date-time
Exec=cinnamon-settings calendar
Type=Application
OnlyShowIn=X-Cinnamon;
Categories=Settings;
Name=Data & Ora
Comment=Impostazioni data e ora

[/usr/share/applications/cinnamon-settings-daemon.desktop]
Type=Application
Name=Cinnamon Settings Daemon
Exec=/usr/lib/cinnamon-settings-daemon/cinnamon-settings-daemon
OnlyShowIn=X-Cinnamon;
NoDisplay=true
X-GNOME-Autostart-Phase=Initialization
X-GNOME-Autostart-Notify=true
X-GNOME-AutoRestart=true
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=cinnamon-settings-daemon

[/usr/share/applications/cinnamon-settings-default.desktop]
Icon=cs-default-applications
Exec=cinnamon-settings default
Type=Application
OnlyShowIn=X-Cinnamon;
Categories=Settings;
Name=Preferred Applications
Comment=Preferred Applications

[/usr/share/applications/cinnamon-settings-desklets.desktop]
Icon=cs-desklets
Exec=cinnamon-settings desklets
Type=Application
OnlyShowIn=X-Cinnamon;
Categories=Settings;
Name=Desklet
Comment=Gestione dei desklets di Cinnamon

[/usr/share/applications/cinnamon-settings-desktop.desktop]
Icon=cs-desktop
Exec=cinnamon-settings desktop
Type=Application
OnlyShowIn=X-Cinnamon;
Categories=Settings;
Name=Scrivania
Comment=Gestione delle icone sulla scrivania

[/usr/share/applications/cinnamon-settings-effects.desktop]
Icon=cs-desktop-effects
Exec=cinnamon-settings effects
Type=Application
OnlyShowIn=X-Cinnamon;
Categories=Settings;
Name=Effetti
Comment=Controllo effetti grafici di Cinnamon

[/usr/share/applications/cinnamon-settings-extensions.desktop]
Icon=cs-extensions
Exec=cinnamon-settings extensions
Type=Application
OnlyShowIn=X-Cinnamon;
Categories=Settings;
Name=Estensioni
Comment=Gestisci le estensioni di Cinnamon

[/usr/share/applications/cinnamon-settings-fonts.desktop]
Icon=cs-fonts
Exec=cinnamon-settings fonts
Type=Application
OnlyShowIn=X-Cinnamon;
Categories=Settings;
Name=Caratteri
Comment=Configura il carattere di sistema

[/usr/share/applications/cinnamon-settings-general.desktop]
Icon=cs-general
Exec=cinnamon-settings general
Type=Application
OnlyShowIn=X-Cinnamon;
Categories=Settings;
Name=Generali
Comment=Preferenze varie di Cinnamon

[/usr/share/applications/cinnamon-settings-hotcorner.desktop]
Icon=cs-overview
Exec=cinnamon-settings hotcorner
Type=Application
OnlyShowIn=X-Cinnamon;
Categories=Settings;
Name=Pulsante attività (Hot Corner)
Comment=Gestisci impostazioni degli angoli attivi

[/usr/share/applications/cinnamon-settings-info.desktop]
Icon=cs-details
Exec=cinnamon-settings info
Type=Application
OnlyShowIn=X-Cinnamon;
Categories=Settings;
Name=Informazioni di sistema
Comment=Visualizza le informazioni di sistema

[/usr/share/applications/cinnamon-settings-keyboard.desktop]
Icon=cs-keyboard
Exec=cinnamon-settings keyboard
Type=Application
OnlyShowIn=X-Cinnamon;
Categories=Settings;
Name=Tastiera
Comment=Gestisci impostazioni e scorciatoie da tastiera

[/usr/share/applications/cinnamon-settings-mouse.desktop]
Icon=cs-mouse
Exec=cinnamon-settings mouse
Type=Application
OnlyShowIn=X-Cinnamon;
Categories=Settings;
Name=Mouse e touchpad
Comment=Impostazioni mouse e touchpad

[/usr/share/applications/cinnamon-settings-panel.desktop]
Icon=cs-panel
Exec=cinnamon-settings panel
Type=Application
OnlyShowIn=X-Cinnamon;
Categories=Settings;
Name=Pannello
Comment=Gestisci impostazioni del pannello Cinnamon

[/usr/share/applications/cinnamon-settings-power.desktop]
Icon=cs-power
Exec=cinnamon-settings power
Type=Application
OnlyShowIn=X-Cinnamon;
Categories=Settings;
Name=Gestione dell'alimentazione
Comment=Gestisci impostazioni alimentazione

[/usr/share/applications/cinnamon-settings-screensaver.desktop]
Icon=cs-screensaver
Exec=cinnamon-settings screensaver
Type=Application
OnlyShowIn=X-Cinnamon;
Categories=Settings;
Name=Screen Locker
Comment=Gestisci impostazioni di blocco dello schermo

[/usr/share/applications/cinnamon-settings-themes.desktop]
Icon=cs-themes
Exec=cinnamon-settings themes
Type=Application
OnlyShowIn=X-Cinnamon;
Categories=Settings;
Name=Temi
Comment=Gestisci i temi per cambiare l'aspetto della Scrivania

[/usr/share/applications/cinnamon-settings-tiling.desktop]
Icon=cs-tiling
Exec=cinnamon-settings tiling
Type=Application
OnlyShowIn=X-Cinnamon;
Categories=Settings;
Name=Finestre in pila e ancoraggio ai bordi dello schermo
Comment=Gestisci le preferenze di affiancamento delle finestre

[/usr/share/applications/cinnamon-settings-user.desktop]
Icon=cs-user
Exec=cinnamon-settings user
Type=Application
OnlyShowIn=X-Cinnamon;
Categories=Settings;
Name=Dettagli dell'account
Comment=Modifica preferenze utente e password

[/usr/share/applications/cinnamon-settings-users.desktop]
Exec=cinnamon-settings-users
Icon=system-users
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=System;Settings;
StartupNotify=false
OnlyShowIn=X-Cinnamon;
Keywords=Preferences;Settings;
Name=Utenti e gruppi
Comment=Aggiunge o rimuove utenti e gruppi

[/usr/share/applications/cinnamon-settings-windows.desktop]
Icon=cs-windows
Exec=cinnamon-settings windows
Type=Application
OnlyShowIn=X-Cinnamon;
Categories=Settings;
Name=Finestre
Comment=Gestisci preferenze finesta

[/usr/share/applications/cinnamon-settings-workspaces.desktop]
Icon=cs-workspaces
Exec=cinnamon-settings workspaces
Type=Application
OnlyShowIn=X-Cinnamon;
Categories=Settings;
Name=Aree di lavoro
Comment=Gestione preferenze spazio di lavoro

[/usr/share/applications/cinnamon-settings.desktop]
Exec=cinnamon-settings
Icon=preferences-system
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Settings;
StartupNotify=false
OnlyShowIn=X-Cinnamon;
Keywords=Preferences;Settings;
Name=Impostazioni di sistema
Comment=Centro di controllo

[/usr/share/applications/cinnamon-wacom-panel.desktop]
Name=Graphics Tablet
Comment=Set button mappings and adjust stylus sensitivity for graphics tablets
Exec=cinnamon-settings wacom
Icon=cs-tablet
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Settings;HardwareSettings;X-Cinnamon-Settings-Panel;
X-Cinnamon-Settings-Panel=wacom
OnlyShowIn=X-Cinnamon;
Keywords=Tablet;Wacom;Stylus;Eraser;Mouse;

[/usr/share/applications/cinnamon.desktop]
Type=Application
Name=Cinnamon
Comment=Window management and application launching
Exec=/usr/bin/cinnamon-launcher
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=cinnamon
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=general
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Version=2.2.16
Categories=GNOME;GTK;System;Core;
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;
NoDisplay=true
X-GNOME-Autostart-Phase=WindowManager
X-GNOME-Provides=panel;windowmanager;
X-GNOME-Autostart-Notify=true
X-GNOME-AutoRestart=true

[/usr/share/applications/cinnamon2d.desktop]
Type=Application
Name=Cinnamon 2D
Comment=Window management and application launching
Exec=/usr/bin/cinnamon2d
Categories=GNOME;GTK;System;Core;
OnlyShowIn=X-Cinnamon;
NoDisplay=true
X-GNOME-Autostart-Phase=WindowManager
X-GNOME-Provides=panel;windowmanager;
X-GNOME-Autostart-Notify=true
X-GNOME-AutoRestart=true
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=cinnamon